# Is there a way to display integer data inside a QTableWidget as hexadecimal?

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have a class that inherits from `QTableWidget` called `InsnTable` and one of its columns has integral data... I want to display the integers as 32-bit hexadecimal values. Is there an easy way to do so?
I think of storing the data as `QString`s instead of `int` and convert integers to hexadecimal accordingly... The problem with that, in my case, is that I have to continuously search for values in that column so I'll have to convert every single data item back to integer in order to successfully search...
So is there a way to only "view" this column as hexadecimal values but have them stored regularly as integers?

I insert the integer data as follows:

```
void InsnTable::insertInsn(const InsnEntry &insn)
{
    this->insertRow(this->rowCount());

    QTableWidgetItem *addrValue = new QTableWidgetItem();
    uint64_t addr = insn.addr();

    addrValue->setData(Qt::EditRole, QVariant::fromValue(addr));
    this->setItem(this->rowCount() - 1, 0, addrValue);
}
```

Comment: Either set a QString for Qt::DislayRole or derive from QTableWidgetItem and return the desired value for data(Qt::DislayRole) or use a custom item delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure:

you can in the part where you do:

```
QVariant::fromValue(addr)
```

give a string formatted as hexadecimal, you need something like this to convert a number into a hex QString

```
uint decimal = 255;
QString hexadecimal{};
hexadecimal.setNum(decimal,16);
```

at the end the code can looks like:

```
void InsnTable::insertInsn(const InsnEntry &insn)
{
    this->insertRow(this->rowCount());

    QTableWidgetItem *addrValue = new QTableWidgetItem();
    uint64_t addr = insn.addr();
    QString hexadecimal{};
    hexadecimal.setNum(decimal,16);

    addrValue->setData(Qt::EditRole, QVariant::fromValue(hexadecimal));
    this->setItem(this->rowCount() - 1, 0, addrValue);
}
```